# jumping to section in TexStudio

Tags: texmaker, texstudio

I have just migrated my usage from `TexMaker` to `TexStudio` and I  want ot get back some functionnality. Indeed in `TextMaker`, when clicking on any section, on the left sidebar, the latex text and the compiled pdf jumps to correct section. But with `TexStudio`, the only latex text jumps correctly. Does `TexStudio` contains such an functionnality ?

Comment: You could use the Forward Search function after selecting the section in the sidebar: Tools > View, default shortcut F7 and also in the Tools bar itself.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, there are two icons in the `pdf` panel. It is necessary to unlock them in order to get scroll going right with where the cursor is at.

See here at the bottom left[image]